# Call SQL Server Stored Procedures from C++ with dbfcmd and dbrpcsend

Tags: c++, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am reading an application written in C++, calling stored procedures from remote sql server 2005 db.

I found it is using two different methods to make the remote SP calls.

1. use dbfcmd

   ```
   int ProcessMsg1(PDBPROCESS dbproc){
      dbfcmd(dbproc,"exec message1_proc '%s'",blk->msgtype);
      dbsqlexec(dbproc);
      if (dbretstatus(dbproc)==-1)
        printf("dbsqlexec failed.\n");
   }
   ```
2. use dbrpcinit, dbrpcparam, dbrpcsend

   ```
   int ProcessMsg2(PDBPROCESS dbproc){
      dbrpcinit(dbproc, "message2_proc", (DBSMALLINT)0);
      dbrpcparam(dbproc, "@MType", 0, SQLCHAR, 4, 4, blk->msgtype);
      if ((dbrpcsend(dbproc) == FAIL))
        printf("dbrpcsend failed.\n");
   }
   ```

I could not find an comparison of two methods from google. Any one can explain the difference of two methods and when have to use what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first one is using string concatenation, a recipe for [SQL Injection](http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/sql-injection.html) disasters, plan cache bloat, excessive server side parsing etc., albeit the effect of these is reduced in this case as a stored procedure is being called.

The second one uses a [Prepared Statement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement), i.e. the right way to do it.

Comment: I thought their differences are related with "RPC"or remote because the second method mentioned rpc in its name. So are they interchangeable regardless the db being called is remote or local?